# Earth connection through resonant inductive coupling with Schumann resonances possible?

Tags: electricity, resonance

I have been playing around with Tesla coils for a while now, but one limiting factor for portability is the fact that it requires an earth connection on the secondary coil.

Since a Tesla coil works with resonant inductive coupling, I was wondering if it would be theoretically possible to wirelessly couple the secondary coil to the earth by letting it resonate with one of the Schumann resonances present in the earth, achieving the same result as you would when you connect it via a wire to the earth.

Thanks!